# CSS element's positioning moved by half in Safari (but fine in Chrome)

Tags: css, reactjs

I have an element positioned correctly in Chrome (Works fine) but in Safari it's off by 50%.  General CSS doesn't stump me but this one does.  I built everything in react and that shouldn't really have an impact on the CSS (I'm stating this just for reference).

The code for the problem I'm having is:

```
margin-left: 50px;
background-color: white;
transform: rotate(120deg);
height: 38px;
width: 38px;
border-radius: 50%;
color: white;
position: absolute;
background: white;
transition: all 250ms;
-webkit-transition: all 250ms;
overflow: hidden;
```

*Edit HTML ADDED*

```
    <div>
  <div class="jbRhCt" style="align-items: center; position: absolute; width: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; justify-content: center;">
    <div class="dbgKej">
      <div class="fCJbKH" style="background: rgb(31, 139, 179);">
        <div class="ijNdlz" style="margin-left: 26px;">

        </div><div class="hOzhhR" style="margin-left: 72px;">

        </div><div class="bPQgoG" style="margin-left: 120px;"></div>
        <div class="dMJdoh" style="background: white; transform: rotate(120deg); margin-left: 50px;">
          <div class="czTFjn" style="opacity: 1;"></div>
          <div class="bbrObs" style="opacity: 1;"></div>
          <div class="ftVltL" style="opacity: 1;"></div>
          <div class="fqOkrX" style="opacity: 0;"><div class="enUBsj" style="opacity: 0;"></div>
          <div class="bSIUmO" style="opacity: 0;"></div></div></div>
            <p class="iWgihJ" style="margin-left: -40px; color: white;">The Light!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

It's off by the top and right and am unsure why. For reference, in Chrome this is how it looks (the white moon)

[image]

And in Safari it looks like so

[image]

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Can you post the HTML also please? Even if it's just what the react code generates.

Comment: yes one moment and I'll edit my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without the corresponding html and the css for the parent element. Since it's absolutely positioned, maybe try adding `right: 0;`

If that throws your moon out of the button, use a `position: relative;` on the parent element.

Comment: added html into my original post, will read over your solution in just a second

Answer (score 1):

Different browsers have different initial points for absolute positioning. So specify coordinates, for example: `right: 0; top: 0;`

Comment: Missed the `position: absolute` in there. Keen eye

Comment: added the html in. I completely forgot about that.